# Not able to save data using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate and am stuck on first step. Below is my entity class.

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
```

Below is my test class.

```
UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
user.setUserId(1);
user.setUserName("Abhinash");

//creating hibernate session factory
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.configure();
// local SessionFactory bean created
SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
//before saving data in db, we need to open a transaction
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);

//once save is done, we need to end the transaction.
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Below is the error log trace:

Hibernate: create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, userName varchar(255), primary key (userId)) engine=MyISAM
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, userName varchar(255), primary key (userId)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table UserDetails (userId integer not null, userName varchar(255), primary key (userId)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439) at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at org.tutorial.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:19)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "engine"
Position: 97
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
... 13 more

```
Hibernate: insert into UserDetails (userName, userId) values (?, ?)
ERROR: ERROR: relation "userdetails" does not exist
  Position: 13
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1366)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.tutorial.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:26)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3297)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3824)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "userdetails" does not exist
  Position: 13
```

Below is my cfg file:

```
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>
<mapping class="org.tutorial.hibernate.model.UserDetails" />
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: what is ur Postgres  version?

Comment: Remove the existing dialect and add this dialect <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
    </properties>

Comment: silly mistake to use MySQL5Dialect. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please upvote my comment if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The key message is:

> ERROR: relation "userdetails" does not exist

This indicates that your Hibernate configuration has **NOT** auto-created the table. You will either need to manually create the table, or add the following hibernate property:

```
 hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Comment: I have the below property in the cfg file: 
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
Although, I added the above and the same error came up. 
Adding the cfg file content as well.